# statsmodels vs R for sample size estimation, why the difference?

Tags: t-test, statistical-power, statsmodels

Why does this R code:

```
delta = 2
st    = 2.8
power = 0.8
sig   = 0.05
alternative="two.sided"
power.t.test(delta=delta,sd=st,power=power, sig.level=sig, alternative=alternative)


Two-sample t test power calculation

              n = 31.75716
          delta = 2
             sd = 2.8
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided
```

Give a different result than the python code:

```
delta = 2
sd    = 2.8
sig   = 0.05
power = 0.8
effect_size = delta/sd
alternative='two-sided'
n = pw.tt_solve_power(effect_size=effect_size, alpha=sig, power=power, alternative=alternative)
print(n)
>17.40
```

I noticed that using the python solver with `effect_size*effect_size` gets quite close, but the effect_size is supposed to be defined as the difference (`delta`) over the standard deviation `sd`, so not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: The Python code is for a one-sample $t$-test. Try the following in `R`: `power.t.test(delta = 2, sd = 2.8, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, type = "one.sample")`. The result is 17.40 which coincides with the Python result. I think you should use the `tt_ind_solve_power` function in Python.

Comment: aha!, you are totally correct. Don't want to have it as an answer instead of a comment? happyt to accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `tt_solve_power` is for a one-sided $t$-test. The equivalent in `R` is:

```
power.t.test(delta = 2, sd = 2.8, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, type = "one.sample")

    One-sample t test power calculation 

              n = 17.40194
          delta = 2
             sd = 2.8
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.8
    alternative = two.sided
```

In order to calculate the required sample size for a two-sided $t$-test in Python, use the function `tt_ind_solve_power`.